# How secure is a Kali Linux Live USB

Tags: malware, kali-linux, antimalware

How secure for the host computer is a Kali Linux Live USB installation?

If I get a virus or any other kind of malware on Kali, can it also infect the computer to which it’s plugged into?

Could it only be a virus or malware that saves itself in RAM?

Comment: How secure for the host computer is a Kali Linux Live usb installation please? - Depends where you got it from. 
f I get a virus or any other kind of malware on Kali, can it also infect the computer to which it’s plugged on ? - Are you running Kali as a vm?

Comment: I’m mainly trying to anticipate the damage of a malware that would be received via a browser exploit/JavaScript exploit/drive by.

Comment: I don’t plan on running it as a VM, just the official Live  usb install.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a computer, running Linux from an USB, and you use a browser there.

Yes, exploits that can take over your USB Linux can also affect the rest of the computer, like hard disks, Uefi, etc. Why shouldn't they be able to? (=> No reason).

Comment: Thanks for your input, there is no way to sandbox the USB apart from running Kali in a VM?

Comment: Breaking out of a VM is possible. And no, as long as your USB device is phyically connected to a computer, ie. the OS is being executed inside the computer and the USB is just a hard drive replacement, there is no way to prevent accessing the computer inside... (And, another topic: There are even harmless looking USBs that can physically destroy a computer when plugged in)